# How to abort kendo chart navigator mousewheel (zoom) event?

Tags: kendo-dataviz

http://docs.kendoui.com/api/dataviz/stock-chart#events-zoom seems to help in disabling mousewheel event on chart area. However, there doesn't seem to be anything that can help aborting zoom event on stockChart navigator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these:

```
zoom: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();  //prevents mouse event

        }
```

or

```
zoom: function (e) {            
            e.originalEvent.preventDefault(); //prevents window from scrolling
        }
```

or atleast you can `return false` in combination with `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: I was able to prevent the mousewheel event over chart area, but chart navigator doesn't expose the same event as chart area.

Comment: after widget is created remove events
`$("#kendoChart").off("mousewheel");
 $(".k-selector").off('mousewheel');`